# Get the clicked element inside webview in electron

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm building an electron app with a webview embedded in it. Just like this.

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Hello World!</title>
</head>
<body>
  <webview
      id="webview"
      src="https://www.google.com/search?q=search&tbm=isch"
  />
  <script>
    require('./renderer.js')
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to get the tagName of the element on which the user right-clicked, and I want to do something with the element if it's `img`. Here's what I tried.

#### renderer.js

```
document.getElementById("webview").addEventListener("contextmenu", event => {
  if (event.target.tagName === "img") {
    const src = event.target.src;
    // do something with src
  }
});
```

It doesn't work, because `event.target` is always the embedded `webview` itself. No matter what I clicked. How to make it work?

Comment: Have you tried `event.currentTarget`? Unsure if it helps. Do webviews behave like iframes? If that is the case, the element clicked on is in the webview's DOM, but not in the outer page's DOM.

Comment: @connexo I've tried, `event.currrentTarget` is also always `webview`.

Comment: https://electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag#event-found-in-page

Comment: Why not use a preload script for the webview? That should work perfectly in your case.

Answer (score 1):

you can't. WebView in Electron is special kind, spawning a separate, isolated process to host contents other than parents, end up most of inner elements are inaccessible via normal html interfaces. Instead, you have to manually setup some IPC between process for specific desired behavior, like webview's preload script sets up ipc listener, and parent send some ipc to webview or vice versa.